# switch between two colors in an image effects - it does not work in some manner

Tags: css

I must have done so that I hold the mouse over my facebook page, the switch to a different image

My code its here;

```
<img src="/img/network/googleplus.png" alt="logo" class="imgnetwork">
```

and i make :hover of it img -> google-hover.png

problmet is how to solve the task to the show a different picture?

Comment: If you're trying to change the `src` with css, you can't.  But you can change a background-image for a div.  If you know the dimensions of the images you want to use, I would recommend going the background route.

Comment: in fact you can just change the `src` via CSS using the property `content` but it works only on webkit-based browsers (Chrome and Opera + Maxthon), while IE and FireFox don't work.

Comment: cant i not make it we js?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
 <img src="img1.png" onmouseover="this.src='img2.png'" onmouseout="this.src='img1.png'">
```